# If $u^*(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{B_r(x)} u$ then $u^*$ is the smallest upper semicontinuous funtion which is greater then $u$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

In the context of vicosity solutions for fully nonlinear PDE of second order (I don't know first order theory) it is useful to define the upper semicontinuous envelope of $u : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ as
$$
u^* (x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{B_r(x)}u.
$$

To prove that $u^*$ is upper semicontinuous I proceeded as follows:

Fix $x_0 \in \Omega$.
$$
\limsup_{x \to x_0} u^*(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{B_\delta(x_0)\setminus \{x_0\}}\left( \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{B_r(x)}u \right) \\
\leq \lim_{\delta \to 0} \left(\sup_{B_\delta(x_0) \setminus \{x_0\}} \sup_{B_\delta(x_0)} u\right) \\
= \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{B_\delta(x_0)} u \\
= u^*(x_0),
$$
the main point of the argument being that if $r$ is small enough then $B_r(x) \subset B_\delta(x_0)$ and therefore $\sup_{B_r(x)} \leq \sup_{B_r(x_0)} u$.

To prove that $u^*$ is the smallest, take some $v \in USC$, $v \geq u$ and fix $x_0$. We want to prove that $u^*(x_0) \leq v(x_0)$. But
$$
u^*(x_0) = \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{B_r(x_0)} u \leq \lim_{r \to 0} \sup_{B_r(x_0)} v \\
\leq \max\{\liminf_{x \to x_0}v, v(x_0)\} \\
= v(x_0),
$$
by the upper semicontinuity of $v$.

> Is the above correct?

Thanks in advance.